# When should I have addresses with #?

Tags: web

When should I have addresses with `#` and when should I have separate address for each page or part of a page.

**For example**

```
https://ca.news.yahoo.com/nick-hornby-boys-read-telling-101350029.html
```

I know sometimes we need to have `#`, for instance when we call a javascript method to show a lightbox(modal) but some websites are using it in their unique address of their pages.

**For example** icloud is using it to show its modal when you click on `create one now` link.

```
https://www.icloud.com/#
```

However, as I said some websites are using that as a method to have unique addresses for their pages.

**For example** following address that is showing a single page of icloud website.

```
https://www.icloud.com/#find
```

Is that correct to follow this practice of having # in our unique address of the website pages similar to what icloud website has?

**I am not asking about icloud.com thats just an example. What I meant is that if you go to www.icloud.com/#find page you would see it is not a single page website because there is just a header, login page and a footer. So why they are using #find and not something like find.html? Is there any specific reason that I am missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL fragments(#whatever) are a way to address sup-parts of a document. You should keep in mind that these are **never** sent to or seen by the server so you can't really use them serverside to differentiate between URLs. You can use them to make parts of a static page addressable or, with the right amount of JS contortions, use them as a foundation for addressable navigation within a single page app. Some JS frameworks rely on this fairly explicitly although with is starting to go out of style as most browsers now support the history api.

Comment: Thats correct but as I asid some of the websites are using that as a unique name for their page take #find in icloud website as an example. Whats their reasoning for that?

Comment: @Jack It's a way to build a single page app. The page JS picks up the fragment and uses it to dispatch an appropriate AJAX request the return of which is then used to render whatever the page needs to be showing while staying on the same page.

Comment: thats what I was guessing as well but have a look at iclound.com/#find  it seems like it just has one sort of data. Does that mean they have a template and based on this # included addresses populate the template?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but if you have a question about how icloud.com works, you should probably write a question about that.

Comment: I am not asking about icloud.com thats just an example. What I meant is that if you go to www.icloud.com/#find page you would see it is not a single page website because there is just a header, login page and a footer. So why they are using #find and not something like find.html?

Comment: It's largely if not completely single page app driven by JS. If you log in, that url will put you on the find my devices page. If you are already logged in, the JS will pick up the fragment and ensure the find my devices page is rendered. That's all there is to it.